# JSF 2.0 with Primefaces 4.0 BPM/IE Ajax rendring issue

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, richfaces

I am using `JSF2.0` with `Primefaces4.0` for now i had Ajax's rendering trouble on each application i developed with using this technology.
The problem is, when Deploy my application on actual server (not localhost), IBM Process Server v8.5. Any of the component is not rendering itself against any event (only in IE) with Google chrome and Mozilla Firefox it works fine.

This problem is still unresolved for now. If any one experienced that, please share

For quick recovery and use Ajax in my application i am thinking to shift on `RichFaces`. any one experience on `RichFaces` and Ajax's behavior on IE?

Comment: A bit of your code would be helpful, are you using p:ajax events or f:ajax events? what JSF2.0 ? MyFaces ? Mojarra? what specific version etc..

Comment: @Sarz IBM Process Server 8.5 can run in WAS 8.0 or 8.5, both of which have a custom modified version of MyFaces that is rather old and buggy.  I believe it is a modified version 2.0.3 of MyFaces.  I have noticed many issues on these platforms as it is near impossible to have WAS load a different version of MyFaces without causing other major problems.  I suggest trying to make a SSCE that runs on Tomcat or Glassfish and see if you can reproduce specific errors. If so then you can submit a bug with IBM support and they have been pretty good about releasing patch fixes for many of the problems.